# Do zombies need oxygen in Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

Cells need oxygen to function and clearly the cells in a zombie are at least partly functional.
In the Walking Dead, do zombies need oxygen? Can they breathe? If they don't have functional respiratory or circulatory systems, do they absorb some oxygen through exposed tissue?

Related: [In Walking Dead (TV), how do zombies walk without blood circulating?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33807/in-walking-dead-tv-how-do-zombies-walk-without-blood-circulating)

Comment: Down-voted due to lack of research effort: Several times in the series, it is shown that zombie heads are still active when separated from their bodies (so long as substantial damage has not been done to the brain) - even when kept underwater for extended periods.

Comment: @Iszi:   This is the makings of an answer, not a reason to downvote due to "lack of research effort" !

Comment: The tooltip for the down-vote button explicitly states "does not show any research effort" as a valid reason for its use.

Comment: @Iszi:  Show me how you "research" that without sitting down and watching every episode.   Seriously.   "Does not show research effort" doesn't mean "OP isn't an expert so let's downvote"

Comment: @ThePopMachine have you seen the show?

Comment: OP could just google it. Was pretty easy to find with just "zombies oxygen walking dead"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### TL;DR:  No, zombies don't need oxygen to survive.  We don't know how zombie physiology works, but we know that they don't breathe.

In fact, we've seen a number of walkers surviving long periods of time underwater.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And at least one buried (but still active) walker.

[image]

It has also been established that a severed zombie head remains active unless the brain is destroyed.  This is relevant, because obviously, severed heads don't have lungs attached to them.

[image]

The zombies in The Walking Dead don't need to do anything, really.  They don't need to breathe, as these gifs show, and they also don't need to eat, despite the fact that they do  so all the time.  Their respiratory and digestive systems are rotten and useless.  They can't breathe, and they can't digest anything.  Since they *can't* do these things, obviously they also don't *need* to do them.

Answer (score 17):

No.  In pretty much any mythology (at least where zombies are dead, not living 'infected') zombies do not need to breathe at all.  There is no explanation given for how they function without oxygen, nor is there an explanation for where the energy they use comes from.

Zombies have been seen to operate just fine underwater for extended periods, and zombie heads are still animate (unless the brain is destroyed) even without lungs.  It is probable that a zombie could function in a vacuum, unless they were frozen stiff.

This is, frankly, a conceit of the genre.  There's no real explanation, and I don't think there can be one.  We do, however, know that they don't need oxygen to function.

Comment: Zombies...in...SPAAAAAAAACE!!!!  I'd watch that.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1642669/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt

Comment: @GorchestopherH well played.

Comment: There is no *scientific* explanation. A supernatural one is perfectly consistent. People assume that the contagious nature indicates a pathogen, but this is almost besides the point. It is not that the bite spreads a disease, but rather that it defiles the victim enough that they too become susceptible to the supernatural effect.

Comment: The particular example I remember (from the comics) is the Governor keeping a collection of zombie heads in water-filled jars in his home, watching them move around like you would watch TV.

Comment: Don't forget S04E07 "Dead Weight" where the Governor watches a zombified Pete tied to a cinderblock underwater at the end of the dock.

Comment: Uh, there's a perfectly logical explanation: pure evil

Comment: @KaiQing - but are they really evil?  From their point of view, they're just hungry.  It's **unfortunate** that they try to resolve this hunger by eating people, but is it evil?

Comment: @Jeff - aah but I didn't say *they* were pure evil. Just that pure evil exists. For all we know the shining holy light hath sent forth these wondrous beings from the earth to feast upon the flesh of the pure evil known as man. I'm just saying "pure evil" is the only sane answer

Answer (score 5):

Why do you assume their cells to be functional? In fact, in every single zombie representation I am aware of zombies **don't heal**. If their cells were working, I'd expect them to have normal healing powers but generally, when you cut a zombie, the cut stays open and you get those wonderfully gruesome images that so enhance our viewing pleasure.

So, while no explanation is given in any canon I know, the fact that they don't heal would point to their being animate but non-living tissue (whatever that may mean) and as such I would not expect them to need or use oxygen, no.

Comment: Agreed, zombie cells don't heal, but they can still be partly functional. Which was OPs point. And a pretty decent assumption, considering the fact that zombies move. Movement in humans is induced by contractions in muscle cells, thus zombies need at least partly functioning cells in order to move.

Comment: @thomax actually, and I realize I'm being pedantic, muscle cells can contract even in dead tissue, a classic example is [pouring soy sauce](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/3134/1306) on a dead octopus. It is a matter of electricity and does not need any living cells.

Comment: Sure, zombie cells aren't neccessarily alive. However, a contracting muscle cell is fulfilling it's primary objective: generating movement. It doesn't matter if this movement is fueled by ATP, soy sauce or magic. It's hard to argue that a jerking muscle cell is not at least partly functional.

Comment: Zombies don't use their muscles to move.  Zombies are powered magically by evil negative energy.  In this respect, they work the same way as skeletons, which are just zombies where most of the body is gone and only the bones remain, or ghosts which are like zombies where no parts of the body remains.

Comment: @thomax Functional != alive. For example, some plant's  [vessel elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vessel_elements) are functional despite being dead cells. Since muscle cells can contract in the absence of an active metabolism, i.e. even when dead, the fact that zombies move is no indication that their cells are alive. In any case, zombies are dead by definition so I don't see how their cells _could_ be alive. The whole idea is that zombies somehow animate dead tissue.

Comment: @b_jonas You know that Karl Popper will rise from his grave and eat your innards every time you complicate a perfectly adequate theory with additional and indefinable variables, don't you?

Comment: @thomax lol :). Anyway, the onus would be on you to demonstrate that zombie movement actually involves contracting muscles, else you'll need to defend yourself from zombie Popper.

Comment: @terdon I'm not arguing that zombie cells are alive. I'm arguing that some zombie cells are partly functional even though the cells are dead. Clearly, a jerking muscle cell is partly functional, even though it's dead. And, with some dead cells being partly functional, the same might be the case for other types of zombie cells, right? Say deficient chemo-receptors for smelling? Or a crazed hormone system prompting the body to wreak havoc? Indeed, why not use biology to explain as much of zombie physiology as we can? And turn to magic only if we must?

Comment: @thomax because biology breaks down instantly in the presence of zombies, that's the problem. As soon as you start talking about dead cells, biology goes out the window and, at best, is replaced by chemistry. Since contacting muscles do not imply living cells, I see no reason why they would need oxygen. If the cells are functional while not being alive, they would presumably no longer be reliant on cellular respiration for their function and so would not need oxygen.

Comment: @terdon Nay, Popper is after you, good sir. I'd argue that a moving human body (dead or alive) is driven by muscles (dead or alive). If you, on the other hand, are suggesting an altogether different cause of human locomotion (which has nothing to do with jerking muscles) I'd be happy to hear. But you'd also be the one introducing a whole new toolbox for the explanation of zombie movement (evil negative energy? whats that?). And thus your innards are the ones on Poppers dinner plate, his saliva negating any need for further condiments :)

Comment: @thomax I beg to differ, my point is that dead muscle tissue is perfectly capable of moving (see the video in the biology.se question I linked to earlier). Therefore, it is you who are positing extraneous forces while I submit that muscle alone is sufficient. Despite being alive. If Popper doesn't get you, Occam will :)

Comment: @terdon I have no problems with dead muscle tissue moving, so it seems we agree on this. My only point is this: A muscle cell which generates movement is, at least partly, functional. This, in turn, opens up some interesting possibilities with regards to other dead AND functional zombie cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just enjoy the ride. Zombie animation makes no sense at all. Especially in severely decayed or damaged state.  Abdominals and disemboweled yet they still walk.  They don't breathe yet they make guttural noises from the mouth.  Can't be explained, but great TV and drama.

Comment: We generally look for in-universe reasons for answers and not just what a user has experienced out of universe. Is there any in-universe information you can provide?

Answer (score -2):

It's obviously all fiction but interesting speculation. The CDC pictures showed brain stem activity so function was to some degree physical/organic. It would seem for even the stem to function there would have to be oxygen/nutrients/etc. I even remember one episode someone saying they do starve but slower than us. It seems they need to consume flesh and this is driven by base instincts from the brain stem. It also seems inconsistent that puncturing the brain up high(chopping top of head off/eye piercing would be effective since it showed clearly at CDC that only base of brain/stem had any activity.